Finishing the ends of brass pins
I'm building an item where I intend to use brass pins to strengthen some corners with the exposed ends becoming decorative elements.
I'm looking for some tips on finishing the exposed ends flush and polished. For the wood I was intending just a final pass with my smoothing plane. I thought I'd read that brass is soft enough to use hand tools on. But I'm doubtful and wonder if that really means modern carbide hand tools, not a vintage Stanley hand plane. I don't really want to take a big chunk out of my blade, thinking I can just plane over the brass to get them flush.

Welcome to Woodworking StackExchange! Does this help? https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5054/tips-for-simple-inlay-of-brass-into-walnut

TL;DR is that you can use sandpaper, but it’s best not to sand in place, to avoid brass particles embedding themselves in wood. I will say I have sanded brass pins in place (with an orbital sander) seemingly without an issue, but your mileage may vary :)

“brass is soft enough to use hand tools on” I think that means hacksaws and files. Not edge tools like planes and such.

@stanch is probably right about orbital sander.  I've had instances of attempting to hand sand douglas fir resulting in the grain becoming more uneven because the soft part between growth rings is easily removed while the hard portion is highly resistant to the sanding action. Brass compared with wood is going to be like the hard part of of DF growth while wood would be like to soft portion.  For sanding DF, orbital sanding gives a better result.

Thank you all - so it seems like the only way to do it well would be to finish the pin ends first, then insert them flush with the wood after it's had its final plane/sand. That's exactly the advice I needed

By the way, you can also round over the ends of the pins (e.g. by putting them into a drill and running against a bit of sandpaper) and leave them protruding a bit, which would simplify alignment. Might or might not fit the look you are going for :)

OMG what a small world, I was just planning a similar use of brass pinning within the past week!

You can get away with planing into brass (and aluminium) in some cases.1 But the only way to know for sure whether it's doable for you is with some testing since there are some variables.
The six main variables I can think of are:

Brass is highly variable. There are multiple types, each with its own natural hardness after forming to shape.

Brass can be supplied hardened or fully annealed, and, possibly in any state in between.

The diameter of the brass rod you're using – obviously a plane will slice off tiny shavings from 0.5-1mm (1/50"-1/25") more easily than 3-6mm (1/8"-1/4")!

Vintage irons can be good, middling or meh. Some are going to withstand this just fine, others not so much.2

Sharpness is definitely a factor.

Last but not least, shaving thickness. The thinner the better.


Maximise your chances of success
Freshly hone your iron.
Adjust your plane for a very fine cut.
Anneal the brass in advance.
Annealing
You can try to assess how hard your brass is by bending some offcuts, or taking some shavings with a chisel; or better, take your iron assembly out of your plane and use it like a chisel (don't remove the cap iron/chipbreaker).
If you easily get shavings I think you're good to go. However, I don't think there's any downside to annealing so perhaps do it anyway?
Ideally you want to heat until a slight glow is perceivable (you'll only easily see a definite red in quite dim lighting). You can anneal in the flame from any kind of gas torch or the gas flame of a stove; if the brass is very thin you can even do this in a candle flame. You could possibly do this on top of a non-induction electric stove, but harder to control obviously and it takes a lot longer.
These are temperatures well above those of even the hottest oven. Wear gloves or use pliers!
Note: you only really need the end that will show annealed, if the pins aren't quite short leaving the majority of the brass untouched could be beneficial once you come to tapping them in.
Let the metal air cool. Quench if terminally impatient :-) (Quenching doesn't harden copper or brass like it does some steels.)
What to do otherwise
If you find you can't plane the pins, even after annealing, or you simply don't want to risk it, then finish the visible ends (file, sand) and tap in until flush, with or without adhesive.
But know in advance that a discrepancy of only a fraction of a millimetre (a few thou) is likely to be visible and definitely can be felt. So if you're not flushing them in place an alternative to consider is to dome the visible end and have them be ever so slightly protruding, which will add both a visual and a tactile element in addition to giving you some leeway on insertion depth.

1 I've done it inadvertently once or twice and I've read that others have too. Heck, you can even plane over some basic wire nails (mild steel) without getting a chip, although definitely not reliably!
2 It's not a given that the harder irons will be best here as might be the first thought – higher hardness can also go hand-in-hand with brittleness and a greater tendency to chip (especially in simpler carbon steels with minimal or no alloying additions like tungsten or molybdenum).
